# How to get values from split function?

Tags: python

When I am running this code below.

```
x="abc=2015 and xyz=1806".split("=")
print x
```

I am getting this:

```
['abc', '2015 and xyz', '1806']
```

But, I want output as `2015` and `1806`.

Can any one please help me.

Comment: ...then index into the list as appropriate

Comment: `print x[4:8], x[17:22]` gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: @Alex.S although it's a little fragile

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, but we don't know what is the OP's general task. To parse out two dates in any string or to get two dates out of string of a fixed format or something else. And for a given question my code provides a good result I think ;)

Comment: FYI, the [split() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) uses the `"="` as a delimiter to return a list of the words in the string. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for more info.

Comment: @scorreia thank. I have check the documentation. But , list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @BHARANIKR, yes that is correct, list indices must be integers. This `split()` is a built in string function that will 'return a list of the words of a string', using an optional delimiter to split the string. The output above is exactly what you would expect by only using the split function in `x="abc=2015 and xyz=1806".split("=")`.

Comment: @scorreia , thanks again. By I am looking for different output. Only the values 2015 and 1806 should be appear. please help me

Comment: @BHARANIKR, you're welcome. take a look at the answer from @AChampion below. If you want to use `split()` like this, then that answer will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print(' '.join(re.split('\D',"abc=2015 and xyz=1806")))

 2015         1806
```

or as list:

```
 print([int(x) for x in re.split('\D',"abc=2015 and xyz=1806") if x.isdigit()])

 [2015, 1806]
```

Comment: If you're going to use `re`, why not just `re.findall(r'\d+', 'abc=2015 and xyz=1806')`?

Answer (score 1):

No need to join, or split if it's an option.

```
>>> x="abc=2015 and xyz=1806"
>>> import re
>>> y = re.findall('\d+', x)
>>> print(y)
['2015', '1806']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well lots of options, here's another if you know that the `" and "` is the separator then you can split on `" and "` first:

```
>>> x="abc=2015 and xyz=1806"
>>> [s.split('=')[1] for s in x.split(" and ")]
['2015', '1806']
```

Or keep the label values together in a dict and just print the values:

```
>>> d = dict(s.split('=') for s in x.split(" and "))
>>> d.values()
['1806', '2015']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x="abc=2015 and xyz=1806"
print [i.split("=")[1] for i in x.split() if '=' in i]
```

Output:`['2015', '1806']`

You can first split and then check if `=` is present and then split by `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "abc=2015 and xyz=1806"
x = [int(i.split("=")[1]) for i in string.split() if '=' in i]
print(x)
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s='abc = 2015 and xyz = 1806'
r='[=\s*](\d+)'
for x in re.findall(r, s):
    print(x)
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.